# Require one of a set of fields in a form to be valid

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I make a Django form where the user can choose between several ways of providing the data, and I need one of them to be valid.

Say that I have a user profile where the user can choose between profile picture as URL or a imagefile:

```
class UserProfile(forms.Form):
    picture_url = forms.URLField()
    picture_file = forms.ImageField()
    ...
```

Is there any obvious way of doing this, without writing my own clean() method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing your own `clean()` method *is* the way to do it.